# In what units does getRawX() and getRawY() return?

Tags: android-studio

```
        public class Test_activity extends Activity {

        int screenWidth;
        int screenHeight;

        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility") //Because I am a dick to blind and visually impaired people.
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_activity);

            WindowManager wm = getWindowManager();
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            screenWidth = size.x;
            screenHeight = size.y;

            final ImageView tree = findViewById(R.id.tree_id);

            tree.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) tree.getLayoutParams();
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                            int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                            int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                            if (x_cord > screenWidth) {
                                x_cord = screenWidth;
                            }
                            if (y_cord > screenHeight) {
                                y_cord = screenHeight;
                            }

                            layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord - 100;
                            layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - 200;

                            tree.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                    }

                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I have an image (tree) which has a 100dp x 100dp size. When I grab the image with my finger, I want my finger to be in the center of the image. The problem is that I don't know in what units getRawX() and getRawY() returns. It seems to be different for X and Y. You might be wondering:

> Does it even matter if it is not "exactly" in the center?

-Not for this application, but for later use it does (at least for me) and upgrades to this application.

> Isn't that something you can find in the documentation?

-Would be helpful, but no. I can't find it anywhere. Just that it returns an integer. And I can't read that, I am not a programmer.

> Why are you a dick to blind and visually impaired people?

-Because it is to hard to create a custom view, and I can no longer look at the yellow background mocking me, like "you can't fix this".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my brother told me. It's in pixels. But I still don't know why does it has to be unsimetrical, to be in center of the picture:

```
layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord - 100;
layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - 200;
```